# Android proguard obfuscate source files and lines although shouldn't

Tags: java, android, proguard

My proguards-rules.pro` looks like this:

```
-keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class * implements org.acra.plugins.Plugin {*;}
-keep enum org.acra.* {*;}
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

we can see there is second line which should not obfuscade number of lines and method name where the erroc occured but here is my stacktrace:

```
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at pl.jawegiel.endlessblow.f.a.b(CredentialsPresenter.java:2) at pl.jawegiel.endlessblow.e.a0$m.a(RestModel.java:1) at f.g$b$a$a.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:3) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) ",
```

especially take a look at `pl.jawegiel.endlessblow.f.a.b(CredentialsPresenter.java:2)` and `pl.jawegiel.endlessblow.e.a0$m.a(RestModel.java:1)` where packages and number of lines are of course not correct. How to solve that? Thank you in advance!